# Is there a Pythonic way to explode out a list of lists with a singular list? (something similar to a cross join)

Tags: python

Let's assume I have these 2 lists:

```
extra_column = [[('trees_trunk_height', 300)], [('trees_trunk_height',100)]] 

base_list = [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon:10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565)]
```

Is there a Pythonic way to do something like a cross join across the 2 lists so you would end up with the below final list?

```
exploded_list = [
    [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon: 10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565), ('trees_trunk_height', 300)],
    [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon: 10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565), ('trees_trunk_height', 100)]
]
```

So basically the base_list gets duplicated by the number of elements in the extra_column list and each element of the extra_column list gets added to each of the exploded lists.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists can be added together, which makes this very simple:

```
>>> [base_list + a for a in extra_column]
[
    [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon:10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565), ('trees_trunk_height', 300)], 
    [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon:10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565), ('trees_trunk_height', 100)]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way for it:

```
extra_column = [[('trees_trunk_height', 300)], [('trees_trunk_height',100)]] 

base_list = [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon:10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565)]
exploded_list = [base_list + extra for extra in extra_column]
print (exploded_list)
```

Output:

```
[[('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon:10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565), ('trees_trunk_height', 300)], [('id', 1000), ('type', 'BigBox'), ('name', 'Mall of America'), ('address', '340 W Market'), ('address2', ''), ('city', 'Bloomington'), ('state', 'MN'), ('zip', '55425'), ('hours', 'Mon:10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7'), ('location_lat', 44.85466), ('location_lon', -93.24565), ('trees_trunk_height', 100)]]
```